# Apache+wsgi python/django

Tags: python, apache, windows-server-2012, wsgi

Windows Server 2012 64 разрядный
Apache 2.4.27-win64-VC11 x64
Python 3.4 x32
Django 1.8.3
VC11 поставил

Апач работает, все ок, НО!

проблема с mod_wsgi

копирую в папку modules, прописываю в httpd.conf, но при запуске Апач, получаю ошибку

```
"The requested operation has failed!"
```

Лог молчит по этому поводу.
Скачивал большое кол-во разных вариаций wsgi  (знаю, что предирчив к версиям и разрядности), но всегда получал такую ошибку.

Мне кажется я все не те версии скачивал или же моя сборка вообще не совместима?
x64 система +x64 Apache + x32 Python 3.4 - это норм?

Помогите найти подходящий mod_wsgi  (я проиграл Googly) или подскажите в чем я не прав?  может апач нужен x32? Но вроде он должен соответствовать разрядности системы?
Или поставить Питон 3.1 х32 , у меня есть wsgi для 3.1 питона, но там 2.2 апач(((  Выручайте!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

снес все и поставил другую (рабочую) сборку:
система х64
Апач х32 VC14 2.4
Питон 3.5 х32
mod_wsgi для питона 3.5 апач2.4 VC14

вся соль в разрядности